# Scraping Training.gov.au of tables

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to automate some of my work. 
The website in question is training.gov.au where under specific pages they nest table e.g. https://training.gov.au/Training/Details/BSBWHS402
Really what I want to do is be able to point at which module I want to work with (in this case BSBWHS402) and iterate through specific tables nested on that page, then rework those tables into a .csv or ideally work into a preformatted .doc

I've been able to somewhat get what I need from the code by butchering others work, but can't get it to look similar to the site in a table.
I've tried to just paste into a .csv and use delimiters, but that doesn't work and is obviously not really automating it.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
website_url = requests.get('https://training.gov.au/Training/Details/BSBWHS402').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
tables = soup.findAll('table')
My_table = soup.find('Elements and Performance Criteria')
df = pd.read_html(str(tables))
results = (df[8].to_json(orient='records'))
print(results)
```

I get the following single line;

```py
[{"0":"ELEMENT","1":"PERFORMANCE CRITERIA"},{"0":"Elements describe the essential outcomes.","1":"Performance criteria describe the performance needed to demonstrate achievement of the element."},{"0":"1 Assist with determining the legal framework for WHS in the workplace","1":"1.1 Access current WHS legislation and related documentation relevant to the organisation\u2019s operations 1.2 Use knowledge of the relationship between WHS Acts, regulations, codes of practice, standards and guidance material to assist with determining legal requirements in the workplace 1.3 Assist with identifying and confirming the duties, rights and obligations of individuals and parties as specified in legislation 1.4 Assist with seeking advice from legal advisers where necessary"},{"0":"2 Assist with providing advice on WHS compliance","1":"2.1 Assist with providing advice to individuals and parties about their legal duties, rights and obligations, and the location of relevant information in WHS legislation 2.2 Assist with providing advice to individuals and parties about the functions and powers of the WHS regulator and how they are exercised, and the objectives and principles underpinning WHS"},{"0":"3 Assist with WHS legislation compliance measures","1":"3.1 Assist with assessing how the workplace complies with relevant WHS legislation 3.2 Assist with determining the WHS training needs of individuals and parties, and with providing training to meet legal and other requirements 3.3 Assist with developing and implementing changes to workplace policies, procedures, processes and systems that will achieve compliance"}]
```

I'm not sure how to work with this exactly, but I can at least notice that it has given an allocation of which column it should sit in.

Very open to criticism and ideas on how to make this product better.
I'm going to make a UI for this to type in the module name, but that is future me's problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly wrong with such output? It outputs JSON format. In there is an array of rows. Try pasting this string in any JSON viewer. For example here https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: I don't necessarily want this in JSON format, it's the way that I found worked. I don't know how to get it from this JSON to .csv
Also, when I looked at it closer, it collates some of the data together, as in all 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 are all in the same data set. On the website, these are seperate lines in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
df[8].to_json
```

use

```
df[8].to_csv
```

and you will get what you wanted.

And to preserve new lines you will have to use other libraries like `lxml` instead of `pandas` since `pd.read_html` normalizes the content.
See [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/24766#issuecomment-455244452) on pandas github.

Here is [example with BeautifulSoup](https://kite.com/python/examples/4420/beautifulsoup-parse-an-html-table-and-write-to-a-csv) :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
website_url = requests.get('https://training.gov.au/Training/Details/BSBWHS402').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')
# The string argument is new in Beautiful Soup 4.4.0.
# In earlier versions it was called text.
table = (soup.find("h2", string="Elements and Performance Criteria")).find_next('table')

output_rows = []
for table_row in table.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.findAll('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
    csvfile.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks, Just one more thing to help with the setting out please.
The line prints verbatim
```1.1 Access current WHS legislation and related documentation relevant to the organisationâ€™s operations 1.2 Use knowledge of the relationship between WHS Acts, regulations, codes of practice, standards and guidance material to assist with determining legal requirements in the workplace 1.3 Assist with identifying and confirming the duties, rights and obligations of individuals and parties as specified in legislation``` 
Is there anyway to separate the 1.1, 1.2, 1.3? And correct the puctuation?

Comment: I feel like I should know this, but ```html = open("table.html").read()``` Should that be pointing at the site directly? I've tried inputting the site into the "" instead of "table.html" but that hasn't worked.

Comment: Updated the example to match your application

Comment: So here's where I hit a snag previously. The site is built so that the Header 'Elements and performance Criteria' isn't the parent to the table. So when I run the script, it kicks up ```table = (soup.find('Elements and Performance Criteria')).find_next('table')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'```

Comment: 1 last thing please, I keep getting error ```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'``` I've been trying to fix it off and on by myself, but find that I'm wandering around in circles.  Thanks,

Comment: Again, my bad. Update `open('output.csv', 'wb') ` with `open('output.csv', 'w')` Also if you use older version of `BeautifulSoup`, you might need to use `text` instead of `string` in `.find()`

Comment: .csv file is created but with no content. I tried changing ```writer.writerows(output_rows)``` to ```writer.writerows([output_rows])``` and it populates the .csv but with ```['\nELEMENT\xa0\n', '\nPERFORMANCE CRITERIA\xa0\n']``` in A1 then runs horizontally in B1, C1, etc.

Comment: Works for me here https://onlinegdb.com/ByGcNAakH . Try adding `csvfile.flush()` in the end of writing to file. Updated the answer.

Comment: You are 100% awesome. I did some more digging and realised that there was something in the file. Opened it in a text file and there it is. For some reason Excel has defaulted the colour to white. Thank you so much. This is going to be an awesome piece of my larger project.

Comment: Hi @SLCH000, I'm trying to format the information that you helped me scrape... I've created another stack question that I thought you might be able to help me out with if it's ok..? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56864726/python-creating-row-breaks-in-a-list-for-openpyxl-to-recognise-in-xlsx/56865742?noredirect=1#comment100434886_56865742)